# Coveralls.io links showing coverage, disappeared from github pull requests, starting 12/01/2022

Tags: github, push-notification, pull-request, circleci, coveralls

Our coveralls links disappeared starting 12/01/2022 from github pull requests & pushes. It was working before. You can see the detailed summary here https://github.com/lemurheavy/coveralls-public/issues/1683. Do others face similar issues? Any suggestions on solution? (We are considering removing & re-adding private git repo in coveralls but wish to not loose our history by doing that)

tried playing w/ different settings in coveralls & github. Our coveralls links use to appear in github repos via circle ci yaml configurations (coveralls/upload)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the late reply. The reason for this issue is now listed under [Common Issues & Troubleshooting](https://docs.coveralls.io/common-issues-and-troubleshooting#issue-not-getting-status-updates) in the [Coveralls Docs](https://docs.coveralls.io/), which were fully updated in Mar 2023.

The root cause is a problem with the OAuth token of your repo "owner." Per Coveralls' legacy integration with Github, which uses an OAuth App, Coveralls needs to leverage the token of some user with access to the repo, and the user they choose for some of these actions is what they call your repo "owner," typically the user who added the repo to Coveralls originally, but the "owner" can be changed by [Coveralls Support](https://mailto:support@coveralls.io).

Since Mar 2023, Coveralls has introduced their [new Github integration](https://coveralls.io/new-github-integration-beta) which is based on a Github App (called Coveralls Official), which uses the app's token and doesn't require a user token for common actions like sending status updates. This avoids problems like the one you had above, where, presumably, your repo owner left your organization or failed to login to Coveralls after 30-days.

The [new Coveralls Github integration](https://coveralls.io/new-github-integration-beta) will replace the legacy integration by Fall 2023, but it's in [beta](https://coveralls.io/new-github-integration-beta) now and you can [join here](https://coveralls.io/new-github-integration-beta#:%7E:text=Make%20the%20switch%20now%20before%20the%20rush%20and%20reap%20the%20benefits%20of%20close%20developer%20support.) to migrate your orgs over.

One recommendation, if you're still on the legacy integration, is to use a "service account" for your Github user and either use that account to add all of your repos to Coveralls, or ask Coveralls to transfer all your repos to that account, which they'll do happily to help you avoid the issue above. That step will at least avoid the issue of your repo "owner" leaving your organization.

I have migrated to the [new Github Integration](https://coveralls.io/new-github-integration-beta) and it works well for me and most of the other users I've helped migrate. Coveralls will add you to a support channel their Slack workspace dedicated to the beta, so you can get quick support if you have any issues migrating.